# Getting gps Lat, Long values from DataBase and Draw marker on map?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps

I am working on a tracking system.
I get gps lat long values from database and then show marker on map,
and refresh a page after 30 seconds to check may b values updated on server.
my code is given below.
may map show page.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html />
   <html>
  <head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript">                    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"> </script>
    <title>GoogleMaps</title>
<script>

function initialize(lang,lat) {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lang,lat);
 var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    var contentString = 'Location NAme';
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Location NAme'
    });
}


function show_map(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
            url: "some.php"
        })
        .done(function( msg ) {
            alert(msg);
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);

            initialize(obj.lang,obj.lat);

    });

}

setInterval(show_map,30000);
</script>

</head>
<body  onLoad="show_map()">

    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">

</body>
</html>
```

my PHP page is:

```
   <?php
          mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die("error in connection");
          mysql_select_db("gpsvalues");
          $result = mysql_query("select * from gps");
         $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
         $arr=array();
         $arr = $row;
         echo json_encode($arr);
    ?>
```

But it is not works fine.

Comment: any error in browser console?

Comment: What you meant by 'Not working fine'?

Comment: @SajithaRathnayake I mean, when more then values in Database table not show more then one marker.

Comment: @Rorschach No,when more then values in Database table not show more then one marker

Comment: i see , then you have to make loop of latlongs to get all markers on map

Answer (score 0):

For show multiple in a map you have to create array for lat long.

```
 var locations;
         locations=[
          [lat1,long1],
          [lat2,long2],
          [lat3,long3],
          [lat4,long4],
         ];
```

So your code should be change like

```
<script>
         var locations;
         locations=[
          [lat1,long1],
          [lat2,long2],
          [lat3,long3],
          [lat4,long4],
         ];
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('maparea'), {
      zoom: 14,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(6.778659644259302, 79.99540328979492),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the add marker function through your php for every row in the gps..

```
 <script>
    <?php
          mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die("error in connection");
          mysql_select_db("gpsvalues");
          $result = mysql_query("select * from gps");
          while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
          {
              echo "addmarker($row[lat], $row[lng]);"; //whatever way you have stored in your database
          }
    ?>


          function addmarker(lat, lng) {
              var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: myLatlng,
              map: map,
              title: 'Location NAme'
          });
          marker.setMap(map);
          }
    </script>
```